# How to get concrete type of a generic interface

Tags: java, reflection

I have an interface

```
public interface FooBar<T> { }
```

I have a class that implements it

`public class BarFoo implements FooBar<Person> { }`

With reflection, I want to take an instance of BarFoo and get that the version of FooBar it implements is Person.

I use `.getInterfaces` from BarFoo to get back to FooBar, but that doesn't help me find out what T is.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can grab generic interfaces of a class by [`Class#getGenericInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29) which you then in turn check if it's a [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) and then grab the [actual type arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29) accordingly.

```
Type[] genericInterfaces = BarFoo.class.getGenericInterfaces();
for (Type genericInterface : genericInterfaces) {
    if (genericInterface instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType) genericInterface).getActualTypeArguments();
        for (Type genericType : genericTypes) {
            System.out.println("Generic type: " + genericType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that this won't work if they define `BarFoo` as generic `BarFoo<T>` and then use `new BarFoo<Person>()`, even though that would be equivalent from "their" perspective.

Comment: Yah. In this case this is my own code, and I am just doing reflection to test it. In my case they will all be declared at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like the following:

```
Class<T> thisClass = null;
Type type = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    Type[] typeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
    thisClass = (Class<T>) typeArguments[0];
}
```

Comment: GenericSuperClass != GenericInterface

Comment: Close, but it didn't get me to the interface. BalusC had the missing link.

Comment: ah missed the difference. Well, use this if you ever need the GenericSuperClass :)