# Gson fromJson deserialize generics

Tags: java, json, generics, gson, deserialization

While working on an Android app I've faced a problem when I wanted to make an ultimate generic methods to send HTTP-requests (with loopj) and deserialize them (with Gson).

As you may know while using `gson.fromJson` you cannot do like this:

```
gson.fromJson(responseBody, new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType());
```

or

```
gson.fromJson(responseBody, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType())
```

Instead of actual object (or list of actual objects in 2nd case) that you've passed as `T`, you will get `LinkedTreeMap` object (or list of `LinkedTreeMap` objects).

If you want an still want to deserialize generic type object(-s) see the answer below.

+Bonus: ultimate generic solution for loopj+gson

Thanks for authors and commenters of these posts:

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/

[How to get concrete type of a generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247058/how-to-get-concrete-type-of-a-generic-interface)

[Java Type Generic as Argument for GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Deserializing JSON object to generic type java object**

First we need to get the actual class of generic type `T`.

We can do it by passing the class itself (`Class<T> cl`) or by getting class from the object with generic type (`SomeObject<T> someObjectWithGenericType`). I will use second case in examples.

Then we need to create a special object of class `Element<T>` that will tell Gson what class to use for deserialization.

```
public <T> T getObject(String json, SomeObject<T> someObjectWithGenericType) {
    Class cl = getTypeClassOfObject(someObjWithGenericType);
    T object = gson.fromJson(json, new Element<T>(cl));
    return object;
}

private Class getTypeClassOfObject(Object obj) {
    return (Class) ((ParameterizedType) obj.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

private class Element<T> implements ParameterizedType {

    private Class<T> cl;

    public Element(Class<T> cl) {
        this.cl = cl;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {cl};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return cl;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If your `SomeObject<T>` is an interface (perhaps a callback, as you will see in loopj examples later), you can use this method instead of `getTypeClassOfObject`:

```
private Class getTypeClassOfInterfaceObject(Object obj) {
    return (Class) ((ParameterizedType) obj.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

**Deserializing JSON array to list of generic type java objects**

Same idea, but we have a different special class to help Gson with deserialization:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(String json, SomeObject<T> someObjectWithGenericType) {
    Class cl = getTypeClassOfObject(someObjWithGenericType);
    List<T> list = gson.fromJson(json, new ListWithElements<T>(cl));
    return list;
}

private class ListWithElements<T> implements ParameterizedType {

    private Class<T> elementsClass;

    public ListWithElements(Class<T> elementsClass) {
        this.elementsClass = elementsClass;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {elementsClass};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**BONUS**

As you will see here `someObjectWithGenericType` is going to be a callback with generic type `T`.
Even though I use loopj I'm sure any other async http client can be used to achieve same results.

**loopj + Gson with generics: object**

```
public <T> void getObject(String url, HashMap<String, String> paramsMap, final GetObjectCallback<T> callback) {
    RequestParams params = convertParams(paramsMap);
    client.get(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody) {
            try {
                Class cl = getTypeClassOfInterfaceObject(callback);
                T object = gson.fromJson(responseBody, new Element<T>(cl));
                if (object != null) {
                    callback.onSuccess(object);
                } else {
                    callback.onFailure();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                callback.onFailure();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            callback.onFailure();
        }
    });
}

private RequestParams convertParams(HashMap<String, String> paramsMap) {
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    if (paramsMap != null) {
        for (String key : paramsMap.keySet()) {
            params.put(key, paramsMap.get(key));
        }
    }
    return params;
}

public interface GetObjectCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T item);
    void onFailure();
}
```

**loopj + Gson with generics: list**

```
public <T> void getList(String url, HashMap<String, String> paramsMap, final GetListCallback<T> callback) {
    RequestParams params = convertParams(paramsMap);
    client.get(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody) {
            try {
                Class cl = getTypeClassOfInterfaceObject(callback);
                List<T> list  = gson.fromJson(responseBody, new ListWithElements<T>(cl));
                if (list != null) {
                    callback.onSuccess(list);
                } else {
                    callback.onFailure();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                callback.onFailure();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            callback.onFailure();
        }
    });
}

public interface GetListCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(List<T> list);
    void onFailure();
}
```

**Usage: object**

```
api.getObject(URL, paramsMap, new GetObjectCallback<NewsItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(NewsItem item) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**Usage: list**

```
api.getList(URL, paramsMap, new GetListCallback<Comment>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Comment> list) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Any improvements are very welcome!

Comment: Awesome useful method ! It works for me !