# Eclipse: SourceType to Class (or get current parameters of the Class)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to search all the classes in a IJavaProject that extends a certain Interface. This interface is Generic, and I want to get the current type parameters of every implementation.

Now I have the SourceType that represents every implementation, but I can't get the current parameters of this class. Here is an example of my classes:

```
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<PersonPk, Person> {
    ...
}
```

My goal is to get the two parameters PersonPk and Person.

If it's possible to convert this SourceType as class, it would be better to manage it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see this answer, this is how we are doing it:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3247137/2895283

Comment: Thanks Peter, but it is not useful for me, cause I have not the Class, I have the ISourceType from JDT... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the type arguments of a type's superclass `(IType sourceType)` use

```
String superSignature = sourceType.getSuperclassTypeSignature();
for (String typeArgument : Signature.getTypeArguments(superSignature))
    System.out.println(Signature.getSignatureSimpleName(typeArgument));
```

Utility `Signature` is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.Signature`.

To get the next `IType` from its fully qualified name use:

```
IJavaProject project = sourceType.getJavaProject();
IType type = project.findType(qualifiedTypeName);
```

If you have an *unresolved* type signature (starting with `Q`), then use this to get the qualified name in the first place:

```
String[] qualifiedNames = sourceType.resolveType(typeSignature);
```

See the javadoc for details.

In the IDE, the classes in your workspace are *not* loaded as `Class` into the current JVM (which runs the IDE), because each change of a file in your workspace would require loading a new class into the JVM leading to huge memory problems, so even if this would be possible by some hack, it is strongly discouraged! The existing representations (Java model & AST) should suffice for all your processing needs.

Comment: Hi Stephan. This returns me the two arguments as String: [QPersonPk;, QPerson;]. But I need to obtain the related ITypes too... Any idea? Maybe there exists any way to obtain the IType from the TypeSignature..? Thanks!

Comment: I extended my answer with two lookup snippets towards the next IType.